# Adding Paypal Reoccurring Payment Option to ASP.NET Code Behind File

Tags: asp.net, paypal, code-behind

How do you programmatically use the below paypal code in the code behind file in ASP.NET?  This will be for a reoccurring or automatic billing option in paypal.

```
<form id="formid" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" runat="server" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="X232455XW">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Payment options">Payment options</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Basic>9.99</option>
    <option value="Advanced">12.99</option>
    <option value="Premium">15.99</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
```

I was thinking you could use the below code, but I can't figure out how to configure the payment to be reoccurring instead of single sale

```
StringBuilder ppHref = new StringBuilder();

ppHref.Append("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick");
ppHref.Append("&business=" + business);
ppHref.Append("&item_name=" + itemName);
ppHref.Append("&amount=" + itemAmount.ToString("#.00"));
ppHref.Append("&currency_code=" + currencyCode);

Response.Redirect(ppHref.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if Paypal has a C# client library? Cause they do:
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/.

Also, why not just use an HttpClient to make a request to their REST api, rather than doing odd things with redirects and StringBuilders?

Comment: Paypal's information and documentation is the worst.  i'll try to follow the instructions you sent to create an application and see what happens.  I just didn't know if there was an easier way to perform a POST and redirect the user to the paypal page.

Comment: yep...that didn't work.  Their SDK sucks.  Can't create an application on their website to get the AP ID.